# Set property in ViewModel within other View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a WPF-Application with a `Window` and a `UserControl`. The `UserControl` is implemented with the MVVM-Pattern. So in the view I have a `Label` which displays the value of a `string`-property called InfoMessage in the ViewModel.

In the `Window` I added an instance of this `UserControl` by

```
<views:ItemInfoView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="itemInfoView"/>
```

Now I want to set the InfoMessage from the XAML of my `Window`. Currently I have no idea how to achieve this in xaml. In code-behind I could access the `DataContext` of my control and cast it to ItemInfoViewModel and the set the value like:

```
((ItemInfoViewModel)itemInfoView.DataContext).InfoMessage = "Hello World";
```

But I hope there's a way to do this in pure XAML. Does anyone know if this is possible and how?

Comment: From my perspective you have two options. Presumably you have a WindowViewModel, I would make ItemInfoViewModel a property of my WindowViewModel. I could then set the DataContext of my ItemInfoView in XAML, I could also modify a property of the ItemInfoViewModel in my Window. Alternatively you could use a DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a Dependency Property to your user control:

```
// Your property
public string InfoMessage{get;set;}

// Register Dependency Property
public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoMessageProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("InfoMessage", typeof(string), typeof(ItemInfoView),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
```

Then you should be able to just set or bind InfoMessage directly:

```
<views:ItemInfoView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" InfoMessage="Whatever"/>
```